# jQuery Ajax error resolution

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, error-handling, stripes

I'm working on a stripes app that uses a bit of jQuery to make the UI more dynamic/usable.

I set up an Error Resolution, so if an error is thrown, the user is redirected to an error.jsp page.

However, if an error is thrown during a jQuery Ajax call, instead of redirecting to the error.jsp page, I get html printed to the page where the result of the call should have been instead.

How do I tell jQuery to redirect if an exception was thrown instead of printing to the page?

An example of the offending Ajax:

```
$.post("SendStatusEmail.action",
            {status: newstatus, id : id },
            function(data) {
                column.text(data);
                column.addClass("redfont");
                column.parent().fadeOut(3000, function(){column.parent().remove()});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    // redirect here.
}
```

I should add that I don't redirect when there is an exception in an Ajax call.  Instead, I have the server return an error description in JSON format and display that in the page.

Comment: Well.. actually the server is handling a thrown Exception, so it's spitting back some html instead of the plain text I was expecting, so jQuery thinks everything went OK.  I guess to use this I could make the exception handler return a 500 HTTP status code or something? hmm..

Comment: Right, 500 = ajaxError called.

Answer (score 4):

What about using $.ajax() instead of $.post()? The more general $.ajax() offers an error callback that you can call in case of an error.